# use of expediency and entail?

Tags: meaning, sentence, ambiguity

I wonder if the following sentence conveys the right meaning.

> Even if they make a big mistake, expediency entails to forgive each other for the bigger cause of friendship.

Can *expediency* entail something?

Comment: Yes, expediency can entail something. It's synonymous to "convenience involves..."  However, the rest of that sentence is a horrific mess.

Comment: thank you for your response. so how can I amend the rest of the sentence?

Comment: I don't know the context of the sentence so it is hard to rewrite. I generally don't agree that friends should forgive each other because it's expedient. Often it is NOT the expedient thing to do, but friendship entails forgiving each other anyway. ;)

Comment: _Expediency_ can indeed entail, but _entail_ does not take an infinitive complement. Gerunds are OK (_expediency entails forgiving each other_), and tenseless _that_-clauses are normal (_expediency entails that we forgive each other_). But not infinitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expediency is convenience, and *entails* roughly means *requires* (or "necessarily involves", since "requires" evokes a sense of active command rather than passive prerequisite). So expediency can indeed entail something, such as forgiveness. Grammatically though (as Prof. Lawler pointed out), it cannot "entail to forgive", since *entail* doesn't take an infinitive complement:

> Even if they make a big mistake, expediency entails forgiving each other for the bigger cause of friendship.

Now it's grammatical, but the sentence appears bloated to me because of using the words *expedience*, *entails*, and *for the bigger cause of*, which are OK in their place, but not among conventional words like *big mistake*; and elementary confustications such as *... they make a big mistake*, which sounds like they're both doing it alongside each other, and any apology would have to be made to a third party.

> Even if one of them makes a big mistake, convenience requires forgiveness because of their friendship.

After all that, I find myself disagreeing with the statement. Friendship is rarely structured on convenience. You might mean to say that their *friendship* entails forgiveness. I'm not sure where *expediency* came from in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive response. So using academic words is awkward when the rest of the sentence is consisted of conventional words?

Comment: btw I'm working on my TOEFL. In one essay about friendship, I wanted to use the word "expediency" that I learned just before starting the essay. Incidentally, I came up with this sentence.

Comment: Yes - Maybe a better word than *conventional* is *colloquial*. Words that are scholarly and rarely used in everyday communication, like *expediency*, are usually awkward near words that are mainly found in an informal everyday setting, such as *big mistake*. And *for the bigger cause of* entails a lesser cause, which is confusing, as a lesser cause is not mentioned .